# Why is the rendered font on my website Arial when I have set font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif;

Tags: html, css

As you can see the in image below, the font-family property of my element is Helvetica, sans-serif, however, the rendered font is Arial. Why is this happening? Now I'm not too sure which font is being actually rendered.

[image]

Comment: Does your system have Helvetica installed and is it available for the browser? If it isn't, the next item in the font list is chosen, and `sans-serif` is the default sans serif font in your system; usually Arial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your system doesn't actually have Helvetica, so you get the next choice on the list.

Setting the [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) doesn't give the user those fonts, it's a suggestion to the client as to which font to use and then suggestions on which to use if the first choice isn't available.

Windows computers aren't likely to have Helvetica on them, but they will have Arial. Conversely, Macs will have Helvetica, but not Arial. This is why the generic family of `sans-serif` exists. It tells the system to use whatever the system default `sans-serif` font is, which on your system is Arial.

Comment: Oh I never knew Windows doesn't ship out with Helvetica by default. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently sometimes the browser will just quietly substitute. In Chrome on Windows, Helvetica, "Courier New" is rendering as Arial, not Courier New.

Comment: @BrianK That only happens when the specified font is not available on the system. In that case the font that gets used will be either: the next font listed in the `font-family` property (more than one font can be listed) or if none of the `font-family` fonts are available, the browser's default font will be used. The substitution will always be quiet. This is normal behavior.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I understand all of that, except that's not what's happening in my case. If my font-family is Courier New, it renders Courier New. If my font-family is Helvetica, Courier New, it renders Arial, ignoring my renderable fall-back (edit: this is the unexpected bit). If my font-family is Fubar, Courier New, it renders Courier New.

Comment: @Briank How do you know it’s rendering Arial? Helvetica and Arial are quite similar and one is quite commonly the fallback for the other.

Comment: @ScottMarcus by looking at Computed [Styles] > Rendered Fonts